# Non-uniform plaintext distribution -- AES attack

Tags: aes, cryptanalysis, attack, known-plaintext-attack

Are their any attacks on AES (any mode) in which before the attack is mounted, the adversary is aware that the input distribution is non-uniform?
Most of the work assume that the plaintext is uniformly distributed.
This is with reference to the following paper-
https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/491.pdf

Comment: Usually there is no assumption that the plaintext is distributed in any way. Definitely not in the standard definitions.

Comment: Many authors assume that the plaintext is uniformly distributed. Please find the link below: https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/491.pdf

Comment: @nivedita: You have linked a *single* article. Why are you saying "*many* authors assume..."?

Comment: @nivedita I'm not familiar with side channel analysis. However, in cryptography, AES is supposed to be secure against chosen message attacks. This implies that the plaintext is chosen by an adversary. And an adversary may choose any plaintext it wishes, and may sample from any distribution it likes. Also in the real world, plaintexts are definitely not uniform. (E.g, if its english the letter t is more common that z). So plaintext being uniform is not usually a reasonable assumption.